# How to restrict the user from checking a specific checkbox together?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

let's say we have this code
can i disallow the user to choose bike and boat together using javascript or anything else

i have tried this javascript code to limit the choices

```js
$(document).ready(function () { $("input[name='value3']").change(function () { var maxAllowed = 2; var cnt = $("input[name='value3']:checked").length; if (cnt > maxAllowed) { $(this).prop("checked", ""); alert('You can select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' options!!'); } }); });
```

but i still need to limitate the choices more and prevent choosing a specific option along with a specific one

Comment: Can you put mutually exclusive options together inside another component, and make them `<input type="radio">`? If they must remain as check-boxes, and 'bike' is checked, should checking 'boat' uncheck 'bike', or have no effect at all? Have you - so far - been able to try and solve this yourself, how far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i have tried this code to limit the choices



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='value3']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 2;
        var cnt = $("input[name='value3']:checked").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
            alert('You can select maximum ' + maxAllowed + ' options!!');
        }
    });
});


but i still need to limitate his choices more

Answer (score 2):

You can unselect all other checkboxes when the user selects a checkbox by listening for the `change` event:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('change', () => checkboxes.forEach(f => f != e ? f.checked = false : '')))
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

---

However, the better choice is to make the inputs [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead of checkboxes.

```html
<input type="radio" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
```

Comment: Your answer is great.

Comment: i want the user to select more than checkbox but disallowed to choose a specific option along with another specific  one 
for example he can choose bike and car or car and boat but he can't choose bike and boat